# Reading from console in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, osx-mavericks

1. how to use NSScanner class in objective c to read input from console ?
   can any one give example for both reading string as well as integer
2. i understand that file handling is another method to read input from console but i am not able to convert the string into integer .

can anyone give example of this too?

Comment: What sort of app; cocoa or command line?

Answer (score 0):

The reference manual for `NSScanner` class is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanInt:)

Note that the `scan*` methods of `NSScanner` class return `BOOL`, `YES` on success and `NO` otherwise

```
NSFileHandle *stdinHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
NSData *data = [stdinHandle readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];

// Scanning int @"45";
int x;
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
[scanner scanInt: &x];

// Scanning string @"hello; world"
NSString *res;
[scanner scanUpToString: @";" intoString: &result];
```